# Storing a variable from an html document to display it in another

Tags: javascript, html

On the first page, the user is asked to select a name from a list (**select/option** tags) and click the "**edit**" button. User's choice is stored using the "**option**" variable and we redirect him/her to the next page.

When the body of the next page loads, it triggers the second function, which displays the option made previously as the main header of the page.

The problem is that, although **onEdit()** runs, **displayOption()** displays the variable as the empty string (as declared above the functions).

Why doesn't the second function "see" the alteration?

```
var option = "";

//"edit" button (onclick)
function onEdit() {
  var selector = document.getElementById("selector");
  option = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;

  window.location.href = "nextPage.html";

  return false;
}

//"nextPage.html" body (onload)
function displayOption() {
  var header = document.getElementById("header-main");
  header.innerHTML = option;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local storage for that, it is easy to use and in this case highly appropriate.

See [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**Example**

on first page simply declare

```
localStorage.setItem('option', 'selectedOption');
```

on the second page get the var

```
var option = localStorage.getItem('option');
```

**EDIT**

as wendelin commented it is even more appropriate to use session storage, because it remove itself automatically.

Comment: Maybe [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) might be an even better fit, since (I assume) the data only needs to be stored temporarily.

Comment: @Wendelin Yeah, can be, but if you call right after get remove, you are good to go also and you do not have to mix backend into it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but session storage does not require a backend, it's just like local storage but gets deleted after the session

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that when `nextPage.html` loads, the entire script is re-evaluated, and option is now back to its default value of `""`.

You'll need another solution to persist the user's choice across refreshes. One of the more common approaches to something like this is to set the value as a query string parameter that can be read from within `displayOption`.